# Select Statement inside of

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." When I set @MonthYear = 2. = to 1 it work just as I want it. What can I change here?

```
insert into #LoansTable (Year ,LoanType,ProcessDate ,Month ,Balance ,RowNum, PercentChange, LastCol
    )
select 
x.YEAR,LoanType,ProcessDate,Month,Balance,RowNum

--,Cast(SUM( Balance - LastCol )/LastCol  * 100  as nvarchar(20)) +' ' +'%' as PercentChange

,case when LastCol = 0 then 0
else SUM( Balance - LastCol )/LastCol  * 100  
end as PercentChange
, LastCol
from
(
SELECT *,
    
case when @MonthYear = 1 then isnull(LEAD(Balance,1) over (order by rownum),2)
When @MonthYear = 2 then (select balance from #MonthlyLoanBalance2 where ProcessDate = convert(Varchar(8),DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(yy,0,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0))),112))
end as LastCol

FROM #MonthlyLoanBalance2


)x
Group by x.YEAR,ProcessDate,Month,Balance,RowNum,Loantype,LastCol
order by year desc, RowNum

Select * from #MonthlyLoanBalance2
```

My code I want to pull the last day of the previous year based on toggle that I setup in another reporting system. If 1 it will return the prevous Month end of month balance. If 2 then it will return previous years end of month balance. (December 31st) Previous month works as desired. Just need the previous years end balance so my other calculations work.

Comment: I can't speak to the semantics of your query, but putting a TOP 1 in that not-quite scalar subquery would make it not error.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at your #MonthlyLoanBalance2 table. Sounds like you are getting more than 1 row for that given ProcessDate but only expecting 1. There’s also a few other things that look weird but might be intended, for example you are doing a `SUM(Balance - LastCol)`, but both of those are in your `GROUP BY` so the `SUM` doesn’t really do anything…

Comment: Note that `TOP 1` might remove the error, but instead introduce a more or less random result. Do a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings? And when you do crazy long date stuff you should comment what it is doing. That is an incredibly complicated way to get the last day of the current year. Also don't be scared to format your code so you can read it.

Comment: @RobinLashof-Regas I just realized you are right. I have not been specific enough in my where clause.